# Consulta sobre salir de while en python al ingresar 10 numeros

Tags: python, while

perdonen estoy empezando con bucles en python, y mi pregunta es si mi logica de resolver este problema seria correcta o si me estoy dando muchas vueltas para hacerlo.
Bueno tengo que ingresar un numero y luego ir ingresando mas numeros hasta encontrar uno que sea el doble al primero ingresado o hasta haber ingresado 10 numeros.

```
#usando esta logica no sale nunca del while
while (int(x) != int(num) * 2) or cant == 10:
    x = input('Segui nomas: ')
    cant = cant + 1
    

num = input('Ingresa el numero: ')

x = 0
cant = 0

#asi fue como lo resolvi pero hay forma de salir del while usando la logica de arriba?


while (int(x) != int(num) * 2):
    x = input('Segui nomas: ')
    cant = cant + 1
    if cant == 10:
        break
```

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos, me ayudaron a entender mi falla en pensarlo con un OR, ahora entiendo mucho mejor la diferencia con el AND

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bienvenid@ al mundo de Python.

**Parece que tienes un problema de operador lógico**, te explico:

Tu ciclo corre si: "El numero x no es igual a num*2" **o** "si cantidad es igual a 10"

**La solución es** Cambia ese `'or cant == 10'` por un `'and cant <= 10'`.

**¿Porqué el 'or' no fucionó?**

Cuando utilizamos un operador lógico 'or' es como decir **o** en lenguaje humano, un ejemplo de un **o** en lenguaje humano es: Tu mamá te dice "Puedes salir si limpias el cuarto o sí limpias el pasillo", no necesitas limpiar los 2 para poder salir, con solo hacer 1 es suficiente, lo mismo le pasa a tu actual lógica, con que una de las 2 condiciones se cumpla el ciclo seguirá, este solo se detendrá si las 2 condiciones no se cumplen al mismo tiempo, es como decir tú mamá no te deja salir si no limpiaste el cuarto o no limpiaste el baño, apenas hagas 1 de las 2 ya puedes salir.

**¿Porqué el 'and' cambia las cosas?**

Ahora hablemos del 'and' o el 'y' en lenguaje humano, si tú mamá te dice "Para salir debes limpiar el cuarto y limpiar el baño" las cosas cambian un poco.
Ahora es obligatorio que ambas condiciones se cumplan y si solo una se cumplió y la otra no, ya no puedes salir. Lo mismo sucede con la opción que te sugiero de cambiar tu while por

```
while ( (int(x) != int(num) * 2) and (cant <= 10) ):
```

Pruebalo así y verás que a lo sumo, a la 11° vuelta se detiene (dependiendo de sí cant inicia en 0 o en 1). Esto porque en el momento que una de las 2 condiciones no se cumpla, el ciclo tendrá que salir.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que de esa forma saldrías del bucle, vos necesitas que se cumplan ambas condiciones para que el bucle se ejecute, si uno de los dos da false se cierra, así es como funciona el and, ya que sólo dará verdadero en caso de que ambas condiciones sean verdaderas y false en cualquier otro caso:

-sigue cuando el primero es distinto al doble del ingresado **y** cuando es menor a 10

```
while (int(x) != int(num) * 2) and cant < 10:
    x = input('Segui nomas: ')
    cant = cant + 1
```